# Best practices for developing locally?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I'm developing locally. What are the best practices before moving to a remote server?
Some practices are:

- First, put your machine name (hostname command in linux/mac) in bootstrap/start.php
- Copy any config file you want make changes that should apply to local environment in a folder called local (in config folder)
- Do not forget to put database file or any other file that contains sensitive information in .gitignore before putting in version control.
- Files that are called env.*.php will put environment variables to the environment you are in, env.local.php for example.

What I want to ask about also, is , should I put composer packages that help in development in require-dev, do you do that?

Comment: This "question" doesn't seem properly constructed. Seems more like a tutorial than a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `help in development` means packages you don't really need in production, then YES.

You `composer.json` can be in production exactly the same you have in your development environment. So all those packages you use only for development, like testing package (phpspec, phpunit, behat...), must be added to the `require-dev` section and can safely stay there. But you also have to remember to update and install your packages by running

```
composer install --no-dev
```

Since --dev is default in Composer: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.0.0-alpha7/CHANGELOG.md#100-alpha7-2013-05-04